# How can I extract values from a column and then comma separate the result in a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, spreadsheet

Given the attached image, I would like to have a formula that can give me the result in the Expected Result section.

[image]

**Raw Data** is where to look, and **Expected Result** section is how I want to get the info, single value and a column which group that person belongs to, separated with commas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Textjoin(", ", TRUE, Filter(...))`

Comment: Yes, but how do you extract the data from the columns ValueA and ValueB? to avoid repeats and then join the text from all the places where it matches the text?

Comment: Use the Unique function to get the list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the words "Value A" are in A2.  Therefore D3 is under "Expected" where John's name is now.  E3 is under "Result" where the string "Group A..." is starting now:

In D3:

`=UNIQUE(B3:B9)`

In E3:

`=BYROW(D3#,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER(A$3:A$9, r=B$3:B$9,""))))`